# Security ESI issue with symfony2

Tags: security, caching, symfony, esi

I'm facing a security problem with **ESI** on **Symfony2** (2.2) :

Some ESI of my application don't require to be logged and are public, but other ESI required the user to be logged and have the role ROLE_USER, for example.

The problem is that every guy can display an ESI, by writing its URL in the address bar of the navigator... So a man can access to a ESI (that is called inside an action which requires an admin role), even none logged !

For example, my ESI "SybioWebsiteBundle:Controller:showEsiAction" can be read at this URL :
http://mywebsiteurl.com/_proxy?_path=id%3D1%26slug%3Dlorem%26locale%3Dfr%26ranks%3D1-2-3-5-6-7%26page%3D1%26isPhotograph%3D1%26_format%3Dhtml%26_controller%3DSybioWebsiteBundle%253AAlbum%253AshowEsi

This ESI should only be visible by logged users : they go to showAction, and inside the Twig template, this ESI is called... But all people can cheat and read thanks to this "issue" !

I searched solutions, I got one really ugly :
check if the user is logged in the ESI action... it's OK, but I'm using **HTTP Cache validation** to optimize my site loading (and memory). So if I choose this solution, I need to add an additionnal ETag that test the user role, to clear the ESI cache each time a none user access to the ESI, and display an empty response, and after if one is logged, clear it again and display the normal view, etc...

I now that people who want to cheat will be uncommon, so it could be a satifying solution... In theory, the cache won't be constantly cleared because of them, luckily !

But I want to know if you have another solution ? Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `<=2.1` versions, the ESI URL came from importing the internal.xml routing file, which exposed a regular Symfony route that was capable of rendering any controller.

If a normal user had access to this, they could render any controller with any arguments in your system, which is the issue you are currently facing.

In `>=2.2`, the internal.xml routing file is gone. You now have a fragments key in `config.yml`. Instead of a route, this activates a listener that watches for any requests that start with `/_proxy`, which is the URL that the ESI tags now render as.

This alone doesn’t help security, except that the listener uses a few tricks internally.

So what prevents an evil user from exploiting this URL to render any controller in our system with any parameters? Since `2.2`, there are two built in protections: trusted proxies and signed URLs.

The class that handles all this magic is called `FragmentListener`. Before it starts serving anything from your application, it first checks to see if the person requesting is “trusted”.

If you’re using a reverse proxy like Varnish, then you’ll want to add its IP address or - CIDR IP address range for the super-geeks - to your config.yml file:

```
framework
    trusted_proxies:
        - 192.168.12.0
```

If the request comes from this IP or range, it allows it. And, if it comes from a local address, it also allows it. In other words, if it’s someone you trust, then it’s ok.