# Symfony 2 the book, Security: Why the additional ROLE_NO_ACCESS in ESI part?

Tags: security, symfony

Why there is a need for `ROLE_NO_ACCESS` rule in Symfony 2 The Book, Security [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-by-ip)? Shouldn't the `access_control` work like a white list (only users that pass one of the listed rules can access the path)? I googled a little and found this [link](http://symfony.com/blog/security-access-control-documentation-issue), where Fabien says about security hole, when the additional rule in the `access_control` is missing, but I still don't quite understand why is it needed? Do I always need to specify "match all users and deny" rule as the last one, to properly secure a confidential path?

Comment: It's explained quite clearly in the paragraph below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is highly recommanded because all users can access in theory to your esi ! But you just need to protect ESI that are "confidentials" (for example, you don't want users to see your admin ESI...)

I was facing this problem, how to secure my ESI here :
[Security ESI issue with symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817671/security-esi-issue-with-symfony2)

Quoting myself :

> For example, my ESI "SybioWebsiteBundle:Controller:showEsiAction" can
>   be read at this URL :
>   http://mywebsiteurl.com/_proxy?_path=id%3D1%26slug%3Dlorem%26locale%3Dfr%26ranks%3D1-2-3-5-6-7%26page%3D1%26isPhotograph%3D1%26_format%3Dhtml%26_controller%3DSybioWebsiteBundle%253AAlbum%253AshowEsi

As you can see, **we are all able to find the URL of the ESI**, and so reading them alone in the navigator. Of course, you first need to find the URL (which can be difficult) and no one lambda user know that. But informed hacker (knowing Symfony) could find the ESI path.

By adding this code (since SF 2.3) :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/esi, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [127.0.0.1, ::1] }
    - { path: ^/esi, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

You said ESI can be accessed only if they are called by the server itself (IP 127.0.0.1), so from a page of the site that loads the ESI, and not by a hacker that load direclty the ESI from its URL ! Users can't cheat by accessing a ESI that are not supposed to see !

**EDIT :**

To answer your comment I'll try to explain the process :

In fact this is a **story of security override**.

**Cheating situation :**

Let's say you are cheating and directly paste the URL in your navigator and load the ESI. Your IP will be something like "88.102.155.96".

What we see at the first in the security config :

```
- { path: ^/esi, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [127.0.0.1, ::1] }
```

As we can see, we are trying to access to a path that matches "^/esi", it's our situation, but we also need to have the IP 127.0.0.1 (or ::1 if you are using IPv6). The **condition is not satisfied**, we skip this line to the next line :

```
- { path: ^/esi, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

The path matches "^/esi", ok, and we don't have the role "ROLE_NO_ACCESS". **The condition is satisfied**. So **the access is forbidden to us** (In fact, this is a trick to protect your ESI, the role "ROLE_NO_ACCESS" will never be assigned to a user of your application, of course !). If you want to be more explicit, you can call it "ROLE_ESI_PROTECTION".

So, in this situation, the ESI is well protected !

If you forget this line, the framework will search a next line, and it will match the line that says by default all the URL are public, so the ESI will be displayed, even if it should be only included by a protected admin page (for example)... :

```
- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
```

**Normal page load situation :**

You hit the admin page which is protected by the role "ROLE_ADMIN". This page includes an ESI in its Twig template.

If I don't have the "ROLE_ADMIN", I can't go to this page, and so I can't read the included ESI. If I want to cheat (let's imagine I know the ESI URL), I can't because you have protected your ESI with the role "ROLE_ESI_PROTECTION" (or "ROLE_NO_ACCESS"), I fall in the "Cheating situation", seen previously.

Now what if I can access to the page because I have the required role :

1. The page is loaded
2. The page tries to include the ESI by calling it's URL :

   ```
   - { path: ^/esi, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [127.0.0.1, ::1] }
   ```

   As it's the page which read the ESI and so the server, the IP
   address is "127.0.0.1" (the only to have this IP), so the
   **condition is satisfied** and the access is authorized ! The framework stops reading here the "access_control" of your security.yml file, it doesn't check the other lines. (Like a switch / break condition in PHP).
3. The ESI is included in the page

So to conclude, ESI supposed to be confidential are well protected because they can be only displayed by pages that users can access with their own ROLE, and not via a cheating way that consists to enter URL of the ESI directly in the navigator.

**Users are encapsulated.**

I can't be more clear, I hope you understood the concept ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't really get it, why I need to provide extra rule to tell Symfony, that "all other users can't access this path". I understand the first rule "only localhost can access the ^/esi path". I mean: if the `access_control` holds info, which and only which clients can access a resource, why do I need to provide the extra rule for all the others, that can't access it to simply tell them: "Hey dude, I have a rule for you, but guess what: you're not allowed". Isn't it equivalent to not specify any rule for them at all, and say: "No access rule for you, sorry"?

Comment: The part, that says, that Symfony will fallback to the general rule, that all paths are public, cleared the issue for me. I was somehow missing this part. Many thanks for your time, mate.